# empty git submodules inside a container running on AKS

Tags: azure-aks, git-submodules, grpc-node

I have all my grpc protobuf file in a single repository and every other service uses git submodules to have access to the necessary protobuf file.

1. each services have CI github actions that build the image and pushes to docker hub on every pull request on a branch.
2. i have CD github actions that deploys the changes of the deployment manifest on AKS.

I keep getting the error that proto files inside the git submodules are not found on AKS, whenever i run the deployment manifest. So i added the proto file directly to the service and everything ran and started fine. i SSH into the container to discover the directory was empty.

Please how can i atleast get this submodule inside container or how can i update that git submodules on the deployment manifest before the container is run. I'll appreciate any help or pointer.